# Multiple Featherlight galleries on one page without unique classes

Tags: javascript, lightbox, featherlight.js

How can I call multiple galleries using [Featherlight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) Gallery without having to use unique classes?

I tried

```
if($('.image-gallery').length) {
    $('.image-gallery').featherlightGallery({
        variant: 'gal',
        filter: $(this).find('.featured-image') 
    });
}
```

but I don't think filter works the way I think it does.

Currently - it loads each item on the page in the same gallery lightbox. I want a unique lightbox gallery for each parent `.image-gallery`. In otherwords, clicking the arrows in the first lightbox gallery should not show me photos from the second one.

```
<div class="image-gallery">
     <div class="featured-image" data-featherlight="http://imgurl"><img /></div>
     <div class="featured-image" data-featherlight="http://imgurl"><img /></div>
</div>

<div class="image-gallery">
     <div class="featured-image" data-featherlight="http://imgurl"><img /></div>
     <div class="featured-image" data-featherlight="http://imgurl"><img /></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd6ucv5s/2/).

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close. Problem is that by using `data-featherlight`, you are using the auto binding, which is not what you want. Turn the auto binding off, or change your markup, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pzfL3rjh/)

Best way is to bind them individually. I didn't test (since you didn't provide a working example), but this should work:

```
$('.image-gallery).each(function(_i, gallery)) {
  $(gallery).featherlightGallery({
        variant: 'gal',
        filter: '.featured-image'
  });
})
```

Note: `filter` is a jQuery selector (string).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This didn't work but it may be an err on my part. I will provide an example in a fiddle tomorrow.  :)

Comment: Hi! I added a JS Fiddle with your solution.  It seems to revert to the original featherlight, without taking into account the gallery code.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my HTML structure as that seemed like the best way to go.